# Difference between these two async functions

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Hello I dont get the difference between the following two asnyc functions, could someone explain it to me? Both of them doesnt return IRestResponse, so I cant access StatusCode field. Do I have to cast here?

```
public async Task<IRestResponse> Post<T>(string Ressource, T ObjTOPost) where T : new()
{
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        var client = new RestClient("test.com");
        var request = new RestRequest(Ressource, Method.POST);

        var response = client.Execute(request);

        return response;
    });
}
```

And this:

```
public async Task<IRestResponse> Post<T>(string Ressource, T ObjTOPost) where T : new()
{
    var client = new RestClient("test.com");

    var request = new RestRequest(Ressource, Method.POST);

    var response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync<T>(request);

    return response;
}
```

Comment: One difference is that the first one will silently throw an exception during the request, while the second will not. Other than that, I am not sure of the exact differences between the construct that ExecuteTaskAsync is using internally and the task factory approach.

Comment: The second is significantly more idiomatic on top of that. It's much easier to read imo.

Comment: Also consider just directly returning the result of your await in example 2.

Comment: If you await the functions, they will both give you the object you want. Honestly it sounds like you don't understand how async works, perhaps a quick read on that would be helpful?

Comment: In the 2nd one only this code is done asynchronously: `client.ExecuteTaskAsync<T>(request);`. In the first one, everything is.

Comment: Moreover, actual IO bound call - network request - is synchronous with the first approach

Comment: Can you explain why one would ever consider the first one to be right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Both of them doesnt return IRestResponse, so I cant access StatusCode field.

They return a `Task<IRestResponse>`. You can get the interface by awaiting the task, e.g.

```
var task = Post(resource, objectToPost);
IRestResponse response = await task;
```

Or in one line (more common):

```
var response = await Post(resource, objectToPost);
```

> Difference between these two async functions

The second example is far more straightforward. The first example spins up an additional task and passes its awaitable back to the caller, whereas the second example awaits the RestClient directly. I see no reason to use the structure in the first example.